# Spring inject XML unmarshalled entity

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, jaxb

I'm working on a Spring application and I'd like to know if there's any way I could specify in my configuration the path of an XML file, having it automatically unmarshalled into a Java object through JAXB (I may consider other libraries though) and then inject it into a bean.

A Google search yields different results but they seem more about injecting a marshaller/unmarshaller in your bean and then doing the work yourself (like this one https://www.intertech.com/Blog/jaxb-tutorial-how-to-marshal-and-unmarshal-xml/) and I'm more interested in delegating this boilerplate to Spring.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can implement your custom resource loader based on this article: [Spicy Spring: Create your own ResourceLoader](https://blog.jdriven.com/2015/09/spicy-spring-create-your-own-resourceloader/). It requires some assumptions:

- Classes you want to load have all required annotation used by `JAXB` which allow deserialisation.
- You can build `JaxbContext` using given list of classes.
- You need to check yourself whether loaded class is what you expect.

### Step 0 - create `POJO`

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "User")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class User {

    @XmlElement(name = "firstName")
    private String firstName;

    @XmlElement(name = "lastName")
    private String lastName;

    // getters, setters, toString
}
```

You need to predefine `POJO` model which will be loaded from `XML` files. Above example just present one class but it should be similar for all other `POJO` classes.

### Step 1 - create unmarshaller

```
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

@Component
public class JaxbResourceUnmarshaller {

    private JAXBContext context;

    public JaxbResourceUnmarshaller() {
        try {
            context = JAXBContext.newInstance(User.class);
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
        }
    }

    public Object read(Resource resource) {
        try {
            Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();

            return unmarshaller.unmarshal(resource.getInputStream());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Simple unmarshaller implementation where you need to create `JAXBContext`. You need to provide all `root` classes.

### Step 2 - create class resource

```
import org.springframework.core.io.AbstractResource;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class ClassResource extends AbstractResource {

    private final Object instance;

    public ClassResource(Object instance) {
        this.instance = instance;
    }

    public Object getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    public String getDescription() {
        return "Resource for " + instance;
    }

    @Override
    public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I could not find any specific class which could allow to return `POJO` instance. Above class has simple job to transfer class from deserialiser to `Spring` bean. You can try to find better implementation or improve this one if needed.

### Step 3 - create JAXB resource loader

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.core.io.ResourceLoader;

public class JaxbResourceLoader implements ResourceLoader {

    private static final String DB_URL_PREFIX = "jaxb:";
    private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;
    private final ResourceLoader delegate;

    public JaxbResourceLoader(ApplicationContext applicationContext, ResourceLoader delegate) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Override
    public Resource getResource(String location) {
        if (location.startsWith(DB_URL_PREFIX)) {
            JaxbResourceUnmarshaller unmarshaller = this.applicationContext.getBean(JaxbResourceUnmarshaller.class);
            String resourceName = location.replaceFirst(DB_URL_PREFIX, "");
            Resource resource = applicationContext.getResource("classpath:" + resourceName);

            Object instance = unmarshaller.read(resource);

            return new ClassResource(instance);
        }
        return this.delegate.getResource(location);
    }

    @Override
    public ClassLoader getClassLoader() {
        return this.delegate.getClassLoader();
    }
}
```

In case resource definition starts from `jaxb:` let's try to handle it. In other case postpone to default implementation. Only `classpath` resources are supported.

### Step 4 - register JAXB resource loader

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanFactoryPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableListableBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;
import org.springframework.context.ResourceLoaderAware;
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.core.io.ResourceLoader;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class ResourceLoaderBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor, BeanFactoryPostProcessor, Ordered,
        ResourceLoaderAware, ApplicationContextAware {

    private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) {
        if (bean instanceof ResourceLoaderAware) {
            ((ResourceLoaderAware) bean).setResourceLoader(this.resourceLoader);
        }
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) {
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) {
        this.resourceLoader = new JaxbResourceLoader(this.applicationContext, this.resourceLoader);
        beanFactory.registerResolvableDependency(ResourceLoader.class, this.resourceLoader);
    }

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE;
    }

    @Override
    public void setResourceLoader(ResourceLoader resourceLoader) {
        this.resourceLoader = resourceLoader;
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }
}
```

This is just a copy of register class from article with only some changes. Probably could be much improved with latest `Spring` version.

### Step 5 - simple usage

Assume you have `pojos/user.xml` file in `resource` folder which looks like below:

```
<User>
    <firstName>Rick</firstName>
    <lastName>Bartez</lastName>
</User>
```

You can inject it into `Spring` context like below:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.ResourceLoader;

@Configuration
public class JaxbAwareConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public AppOwner appOwner(ResourceLoader resourceLoader) {
        ClassResource resource = (ClassResource) resourceLoader.getResource("jaxb:pojos/user.xml");
        User user = (User) resource.getInstance();

        return new AppOwner(user);
    }
}
```

A little bit unpleasant is casting resource to `ClassResource` and instance to `User` class but it is a downside of this solution.

Comment: Thanks, I thought there would be for sure a built-in feature in Spring for this, since it seems a likely scenario to have an xml configuration in some app and wanting to inject that but apparently I'll have to implement this myself